# Is this a good way to create a namespace in javascript?

Tags: javascript, javascript-namespaces

I have been reading a bunch of posts, questions, and articles on the use of the `with` keyword in JavaScript. Some of the articles warn against the use of Javascript's `with` keyword, so I'd like to know if my use is appropriate.

Most of my programming experince is in C# and Java, so when creating related objects namespacing them made sense to me.

The approach I am trying is to first create the root namespace as a globally accessible object. The objects members are the first level namespaces which are also objects.

When to add object to the namespace, I use the Javascript `with` keyword to make the members of the argument locally accessible withing the scope of the with. As you move through the namespace, you nest `with`s and set the argument to the namespace to be entered.

Here is an example:

```
var Namespace = {
    SubNamespace1: {},
    SubNamespace2: {}

}
with (Namespace) {

    with (SubNamespace1) {

        SubNamespace1.FirstClass = {
            foo: function() {
                SecondClass.bar();
            },
            bar: function() {
                SecondClass.foo();
            }

        },
        SubNamespace1.SecondClass = {
            foo: function() {
                FirstClass.bar();
            },
            bar: function() {
                FirstClass.foo();
            }
        }
    }

    with (SubNamespace2) {

        SubNamespace2.FirstClass = {
            foo: function() {
                SecondClass.bar();
            },
            bar: function() {
                SecondClass.foo();
            }
        },
        SubNamespace2.SecondClass = {
            foo: function() {
                FirstClass.bar();
            },
            bar: function() {
                FirstClass.foo();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Using `with` is not recommended. [with Statement Considered Harmful](http://yuiblog.com/blog/2006/04/11/with-statement-considered-harmful/).

Comment: `with` will throw an error in ES5 strict plus it's slooow. Better not to use it. Can't you just use the full path? Or maybe a module pattern?

Comment: Give [this](http://addyosmani.com/blog/essential-js-namespacing/) a read, it might help you out with a solid namespace setup